# Google classic vs universal analytics visit count

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

As [recommended](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2817075?hl=en) by Google, we are testing universal analytics by using both classic and universal (ga.js and analytics.js) on our site right now.
Quite randomly, I decided to compare data between the two accounts.

I was quite surprised by what I found: visits count, as well as visitor count differ by close to 30%:

- 1492 visits yesterday according to classic analytics
- 1005 accorting to universal)

Also, pageviews, for instance, are roughly the same (3409 for classic, 3391 for universal).

Note that the session duration was kept by default at 30 minutes so 'visits' should have the same meaning in both cases, right?

Is this an expected behaviour or are we doing something wrong?

Comment: I think there is an issue on googles side. I see something similar, on Aug 6th, the traffic on the universal profile doubled over the classic one. I've seen it happen before but it often gets corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out where this was coming... and that was stupid.
I'm posting the answer in case it helps someone out there.

A few weeks ago we introduced event-tracking but server side (when a user logs in typically).
As far as universal was concerned, we were able to retrieve the client id and send it to ga so  all went well.

But for classic analytics, you cannot send the client id. As a results all the "logged in" visits were duplicated...